# --= and ++= complexity on Scala ArrayBuffer

Tags: scala, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I wish to well understand complexity associate with this two function in order to accomplish a proper complexity comparison.

My problem is that i want to create an array from another of size n. When the first becomes smaller and smaller until being empty, the other get bigger and bigger until have the n size as following.

```
while( ArrayBuffer2.size != n ) {
  ArrayBufferX = ArrayBuffer1.filter(...)
  ArrayBuffer1 --= ArrayBufferX
  ArrayBuffer2 ++= ArrayBufferX
}
```

I know that the complexity depends on the number of iteration can we tell that in average it takes k iterations.

My second question is what becomes the complexity when i cut my first array into b buckets.

Let's suppose that we have an ArrayBuffer of size n and we cut it in two piece of size n/2 on which we apply the same steps as above knowing that in general the number of iteration requiered is less important than if we've got one array.

I hope that i was clear enough.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to do from that explanation.

Comment: I want to estimate the complexity in big O notation of that piece of code.

Comment: This boils down to `System.arraycopy` which is `O(n)` for `++=` and `O(n)` for the removal of `--=`.

Answer (score 0):

As the array size is n and one item is moved from one array to another at each step, it will take n iterations. So the complexity is O(n). If you break up into multiple buckets, the problem is still the same. You still need n operations to put data in second array. Your source has changed but number of operations has not changed.

Comment: In fact, we take a subarray of the first which is introduce in the second knowing that the size of the subarray is not the same even if we restart the experiment. Thus the number of iteration is moving from one experiment to another.